# How do I prevent angular service from being destroyed on page reload?

Tags: angular, websocket

I have a web socket service which is declared in my module, and I want to only have to set it up once (when I first enter the application), and then have it destroyed only when a user quits the page. I could just reinitialize the service fields when the user reloads the page, but I was hoping there would be a way of doing it only once.

For example, I set up a socket in page 1, I want that socket/ socket connection to stay live when I reload on any page... I don't want to have to reconnect. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Your app state is reloaded at every page refresh or a a new accesing on your website.

Is not like you can store your service in a localStorage as a data object. Your service is instantiated only once (singleton) at the app load.

I had same problem like yours. A socket connection will be closed immediatelly when you will destroy the session (quit or reload the page ...., even for inactivity).